# How do I make an extention for PSPad?

Tags: api, plugins, documentation, pspad

I have used PSPad alot and I would like to make an extension for PSPad, but I don't know how to do it. I cannot find anywhere an API documentation to make the extensions.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [Script User's Guide](http://gogogadgetscott.info/pspad/scripts.htm)?  I would think if you looked at some existing extensions that you like you will quickly discover how they hook into the defined APIs.

Comment: Yea, I found the Script User's Guide a half hour after I posted the question. Thanks for answering